# Netscape 3.0 is not supported very well

Tags: discussion, bug, april-fools, time-machine

Your website has a claim below:

[image]

Unfortunately it is not true. Your site does not load very well at all in Netscape 3.0. In fact, a number of links do not appear to be working, nor does the awesome mouse trailer. On the other hand if I load it your site with [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) it looks much better and everything appears to be functioning as expected.

My stats: 14.4 kbit/s modem, 8 MB RAM, P75, and Red Hat Linux 5.1.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Does not work on Netscape Navigator 3.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326023/289905).

Comment: another example of bloated 90's website.

Comment: How did you get Netscape 3.0 to take the cert at all? It doesn't even support sha256.

Comment: @Joshua, check the date of the OP!

Comment: this belongs on mse, and despite being rooted in the time-machine related redesign, can be taken as part of a broader accessability issue.  i'm glad to hear it shows up at all, as the existing post on mse was weakly tested.